# How can we check seperately true/false if empty string [eg: ' '] or string contain only white spaces [eg: ' ']?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi team Iam new to react and javascript. Iam working on some validation parts. I need to take input only if it is either an empty string or a non empty string but it shouldn't be only white spaces..? how can I check that condition?

```
var element='' // this should take 
var element='       ' // this shouldnot (bcz contain only empty space) 
var element='Hai how are you'  // this should take
var element='  jji       hooy      ' // this should also take
```

Can someone help i used trim() but if so it cant identiy '' and '  '

any other solution

Comment: *"Can someone help i used trim()"* show us please what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *regular expression* to match strings that contain *only* whitespace.

```js
!/^\s+$/.test('');    // true
!/^\s+$/.test('   '); // false
!/^\s+$/.test('Hai how are you');        // true
!/^\s+$/.test('  jji       hooy      '); // true
```

- `!` means ‘not’
- `^` means ‘start of string’
- `$` means ‘end of string’
- `\s+` means ‘whitespace, one or more times’

Comment: A regexp-only variation of this (no negation mark !), could be: `/\S|^$/.test(...)`. `\S` means anything that is not a space (please not the _capital_ S). `^$` means empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it like this:

```
validate(element) {
    return element.length && element.trim().length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
if(str.length && str.trim() === ""){
    return false
  }else{
    return true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input value has no length, set the state. If the input value *has* length, and when you trim it it still has length, set the value. Otherwise don't set the input state.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {

    // Get the value, and the length of the value
    const { value, value: { length } } = e.target;

    // Check the condition, set the state
    if (!length || (length && value.trim().length !== 0)) {
      setInput(value);
    }
  }

  // Log the updated state
  useEffect(() => console.log(`Current state: ${input}`), [input]);

  return <input onChange={handleChange} />;

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```